# KafkaSpout not receiving messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm trying to integrate Kafka (Kafka_2.10 version 0.8.2.1) with Storm (version 0.9.3) in Cloudera environment, and have written some code for producers/consumers. I'm able to run the producer code separately with Kafka and see that it is working with my consumer code (on console). I then wrote some code using KafkaSpout and HDFSBolt to write data into HDFS. With this code, I am able to create a topology (and see it in the UI), but the the KafkaSpout is not receiving any messages from the producer.

My code snippet is shown below:

```
public class LoadingData {


public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {

    String kafkaTopic = "test";

    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(new ZkHosts("localhost:2181"),
            kafkaTopic, "/kafkastorm", "KafkaSpout");    


    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig),4);

    RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter(",");
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(10); 
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(5.0f, Units.MB); 
    FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat().withPath("/stormstuff");

    builder.setBolt("stormbolt", new HdfsBolt()
                    .withFsUrl("hdfs://localhost:8020")
                    .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
                    .withRecordFormat(format)
                    .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
                    .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat),1
                    ).shuffleGrouping("KafkaSpout");


    String topologyName = "EmployeeTopology";
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setNumWorkers(1);

    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, config, builder.createTopology());

}
```

}

Any ideas/suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? I really appreciate your help! Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Did you use the same topic throughout?

Comment: are you able to see if the tuple is getting emitted from the spout?

Comment: can you post a picture from the storm UI? "bin/storm ui" to start it, and then go in your browser to http://localhost:8080

Comment: Did you check the Storm log files for errors?

Comment: @Chris - i am using same topic throughout

Comment: @user2720864 - No, I am not able to see any tuple that is getting emitted from the spout.

Comment: @SQL.injection - I am not able to post the image. But in the UI, I am able to see the topology being created successfully without any errors.

Comment: @Matthias - I am able to create the topology successfully without any errors. So I didn't check the logs.

Comment: You should check the log. Maybe there are some errors from the spout. Because it does no emit any tuples it might fail to connect to kafka.

Comment: If you (1) write some messages to a topic, (2) read them with one consumer group, (3) read them from another consumer group with the KafkaSpout then the spout won't read any messages, even though it uses a different consumer group name.  See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899163/how-do-i-use-multiple-consumers-in-kafka) question, although it describes a different scenario than yours.

Comment: can you please try changing the groupId while configuring the spout